# Are Dr. Abdul Kalam's principles opposite to Hinduism?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, non-attachment

Hinduism talks about non attachment to things and attachment to God. [Sri Krishna says about leaving](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/2/verse/62) kaama, krodha, lobha, moha, madha, maatsalyam etc.

[Dr. Abdul Kalam said](https://m.hindustantimes.com/india/dream-dream-dream-10-quotes-from-kalam-that-ignite-minds/story-IvhhmqoucInttWZV8o82vJ.html) to dream, have attachment, and work hard hard to fulfill that dream.

> 1. My message, especially to young people is to have courage to think differently, courage to invent, to travel the unexplored path, courage to discover the impossible and to conquer the problems and succeed.

> 2. Dream, dream, dream! Conduct these dreams into thought, and then transform them into action.

> 3. Each setback teaches us a new facet of life and something about our own personalities. When we tackle obstacles, we find hidden reserves of courage and resilience we did not know we had.

Did Dr. Kalam misguide Hindus with his own principles? Did that increased Angry men (Krodha) in the country? Krodha is the result of Kaama right?

As per the Hinduism, if a person has desire (kaama) to get something, and if he did not get that, then he will get angry (krodha).

Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: Abdul Kalam himself was not a Hindu, then why do you expect his views to match with those of Hinduism in the first place? Secondly, what he said is correct in a context. If one thinks that is opposite of Hindu thought then it is misinterpretation of scriptures. And, lastly I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: Unless Abdul Kalam specifically commented on the BG as a whole or a specific verse from BG and you are asking for a clarification on it, this question is off-topic for the site.

Comment: Whatever may be our reservations on the opinions expressed by Dr. Kalam, we should remember that he was ex-President of India.  We should precede his name either with Sri or Dr., in my opinion.

Comment: Sure, sorry but I got it @Srimannarayana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-attachment, as enshrined in Upanishads/Bhagawad Gita, is required when ONE is practicing SPIRITUAL aspects as a long term goal, parallel to one's day to day affairs, which are to be discharged, in order to get rid of one's own prArabdha.

However, when ONE is required to achieve something materialistic for self or **though for the benefit of the society as a whole**, ONE should **have a dream,** passion to remain fixed on target , and determination to achieve the goal. So both the aspects are different.

The following words of Swami Vivekananda should be remembered.

- Our duty to others means helping others; doing good to the world. Why should
  we do good to the world? Apparently to help the world, but really to help
  ourselves. We should always try to help the world, that should be the highest
  motive in us; but if we consider well, we find that the world does not require
  our help at all.
- Arise awake and stop not till your goal is reached
- “[To succeed](https://www.narendramodi.in/igniting-young-minds-swami-vivekanandas-success-mantras-for-youth-4554), you must have tremendous perseverance, tremendous will. ‘I will drink the ocean’, says the persevering soul; ‘at my will mountains will crumble up’. Have that sort of energy, that sort of will; work hard, and you will reach the goal.”

---

We have to remember that even Sri Krishna encouraged Arjuna to fight .  Does it mean that Sri Krishna became a cause for hatred, strong desire,  etc, in Arjuna?

No!  Sri Krishna advised Arjuna to do his duty.

And, Dr. Kalam was right in stating so.

Comment: Sri Krishna to do work for the satisfaction of Krishna or Vishnu, not for oneselves satisfaction this path is called  karma yoga.

Comment: Your comment is not clear.  Can you elaborate further? @guhan

Comment: we must not do any work for our satisfaction we must act for the satisfaction of god.

Comment: What you are saying is correct as far as humans are engaged in SPIRITUAL pursuits.   That is the ULTIMATE aim.  However, in respect of huge ordinary people, we cannot apply the rule of **we must not do any work for our satisfaction we must act for the satisfaction of god**, because their maturity levels will be different.  @guhan